# pageViews - Name column (letters before page name)

Tags: azure-application-insights

Azure Application Insights - pageViews - Name column is showing some letters before the page name. not sure what these are as there are duplicates pages showing with a different letter (e, n, l, t). Would like to know where to find information about this.

t login
l home

Answer (score 0):

By default the SDK sends the title of each page as the page view name. Check whether the page view names are specified manually in code or if they're being sent automatically by the Application Insights SDK:

- If the page view names are manually specified in code using the
  trackPageView API, change the name to be less specific. Avoid common
  mistakes like putting the URL in the name of the page view. Instead,
  use the URL parameter of the trackPageView API. Move other details
  from the page view name into custom properties.
- If the Application Insights SDK is automatically sending page view names, you can either change your pages titles or switch to manually sending page view names. The SDK sends the title of each page as the page view name, by default. You could change your titles to be more general, but be mindful of SEO and other impacts this change could have. Manually specifying page view names with the trackPageView API overrides the automatically collected names, so you could send more general names in telemetry without changing page titles.

Additional documentation reference

[Naming Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-troubleshoot)

[Custom Events for page View Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778932/how-to-provide-custom-names-for-page-view-events-in-azure-app-insights)

Hope the above information helps.